# gradle Difference between jar and assemble task

Tags: gradle

what is the difference between `assemble` and `jar` task of `java plugin` in gradle?

I tried executing them with a sample Hello world project they both seems to do the same job.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since `jar` is a single task, which assembles a jar-archive for current project, `assemble` is, according to [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#lifecycle_tasks):

> assemble   All archive tasks in the project, including jar. Some plugins add additional archive tasks to the project.  Task    Assembles all the archives in the project.

It is build-cycle task, which execute all the task of this build-cycle phase. Like a `check` task, which runs all test and verification task, `assemble` Runs all task, which essemble some artifacts. And the 'jar' could be not the only such a task in the project, some plugins could add them too.